# Splitting string based on prefix?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this string:

> "asd:apples are nice qwe: bananas are cool zxc: orang:es taste bad iop:pineapples are sweet asd: strawberry is my favorite"

I would like this to be returned, so that the order the fruits appear in stay the same:

```
[
  {"asd": "apples are nice"},
  {"qwe": "bananas are cool"},
  {"zxc": "orang:es taste bad"},
  {"iop": "pineapples are sweet"},
  {"asd": "strawberry is my favorite"}
]
```

I have another array with all of the keys that the function should check for like:

> ["asd", "qwe", "zxc", "iop"]

How would I do this? This is what I have tried so far:

```
let arr = text.split(":"); // But when I do this it also splits "orang:e" from the key "zxc"
```

Comment: Regex is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regexp instead of a string to pass into [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split):

```
// split by "fruit[number]:", sometimes followed by a space
const fruitSeparatorRegexp = /fruit\d:\s*/;

// example usage: fruitStringToObj("apple", 2); // -> {fruit2: "apple"}
const fruitStringToObj = (fruitName, index) => ({ [`fruit${index}`]: fruitName.trim() });

"fruit1:apple fruit2: banana fruit3: orang:e fruit4:pineapple"
    .split(fruitSeparatorRegexp)
    .map(fruitStringToObj)
    .slice(1) // remove empty 0 index item
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "fruit1": "apple"
    },
    {
        "fruit2": "banana"
    },
    {
        "fruit3": "orang:e"
    },
    {
        "fruit4": "pineapple"
    }
]
```

Comment: I like this approach, but what if indexes are not consecutive or don't start with 1?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I actually do not want fruit (1, 2, 3) and instead wanted the actual key name that was used, I edited my question to show this.

Comment: @Mosukoshide In that case you should probably use a strategy that uses match() to split up the string - this would be the first step: "asd:apple qwe: banana zxc: orang:e iop:pineapple".match(/\w+:\s*(\w|:)+/g)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need a dynamic Regex pattern that uses the keys that you have previously registered. That can be achieved with `RegExp`

Something like this might work:

```js
const str = "asd:apple qwe: banana zxc: orang:e iop:pineapple";
const keys = ["asd", "qwe", "zxc", "iop"];

const data = [];

keys.forEach(key => {
    const rgx = new RegExp(`${key}:\\s*([^\\s]*)`);
    const match = str.match(rgx);

    if (!match[1]) return;

    data.push({ [key]: match[1] });
})

console.log(data);
```

Here I dynamically build a Regex using each key and then get a match, extra `\` characters were needed in order to escape them from the string. Then you just generate the objects and if no match was found skip that key.

Comment: Thanks for this! How would this function be able to use sentences with multiple words though? I edited my question to show what I'm talking about.